# Can't get HTTPS access to Commento service running on AWS with Google domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I have Commento++ running on my AWS Instance
It is configured to run on 0.0.0.0:443 with origin set to SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM and it is running successfully
I have opened port 443 to inbound and outbound traffic

The domain is through Google Domains, and I have redirected SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM to the static IP of the aws instance

I have created an SSL Certificate in AWS certificate manager for SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM and added the equivalent CNET record on Google Domains and the certificate has been issued successfully.

But when I go to the website, https://SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM I get the following error:

This site can’t provide a secure connection
SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

When I set commento++ up on port 80, it works via http but not https. I assumed I could set it up on port 80, add the AWS SSL certificate and the https would work automatically but I guess that is wrong. And setting up to work on 443 doesn't work either.

From what I can tell, I need to set up an NGINX proxy so that external connections can come through port 443 but my local instance of commento can run on port 80. Is that correct? How do I get the actual certificate keys etc?